# Exception: unknown error: Chrome version must be >= 53.0.278 5.0

Tags: google-chrome, protractor, selenium-chromedriver, e2e-testing, angularjs-e2e

I am trying to setup e2e test using protractor, keep on getting Chrome version must be >= 53.0.278 5.0 error.

Environment: 
OS: Windows 7(64 bit)
Chrome: 44(I am not allowed to upgrade to latest version)
Protractor: 5.0.0
ChromeDriver: 2.26
SeleniumStandalone: 2.53.1

Thanks.

Comment: If you cant upgrade your browser then you have to downgrade something else. probably just the driver, maybe protractor too

Comment: Thanks for response Gunderson, I have tried downgrading chrome driver to 2.20, after this most of the test cases fails with common error message "element is not clickable".. and I am sure that these test cases are working fine in my colleagues system..

Answer (score 0):

ChromeDriver 2.26 supports Chrome v53-55 as described [here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.26/notes.txt).

Downgrade your ChromeDriver with the command `webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 2.20`. This would install ChromeDriver 2.20 which is compatible with Chrome v43-48.

Comment: Thanks for your response Mezo, yes I have tried that also.. when I have installed 2.20 in that case most of the test fails, it has a common error message "element is not clickable".. but these tests are running successfully in my colleagues system, and they have quite higher chrome version 55. So I don't think problem with test cases.. might be I am missing something in configuration for chrome 44.

Comment: Yeah, well Chrome 44 is more than 2 years old now... A lot of changes happened since then and it is possible that something is not compatible either in the app or in the test suite with your version. `Element is not clickable` is a pretty easy error to debug though - I'd `browser.pause()` just before the error is thrown and check the state of the app.